# Determine total amount of top result returned

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sum

I would like to determine two things from a single query:

1. Most prevalent column in a table
2. The amount of times such column was located upon querying the table

Example Table:

```
user_id      some_field
1                data
2                data
1                data
```

The above would return user_id # 1 as being the most prevalent in the table, and it would return (2) for the total amount of times that it was located in the table.

I have done my research and I came across two types of queries.

> 1. GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
> 2. SUM

The problem is that I can't figure out how to use these two queries in conjunction with one another. For example, consider the following query which successfully returns the most prevalent column.

```
$top_user = "SELECT user_id FROM table_name GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC";
```

The above query returns "1" based on the example table shown above. Now, I would like to be able to return "2" for the total amount of times the user_id (1) was found in the table.

Is this by any chance possible?

Thanks,

Evan

Comment: Are the data in the some_field always the same for the same user_id?

Comment: No They are not always the same.

Comment: @Mark Wilkins solution is the one you are looking for then. If it were the same i would suggest you omit multiple entries for the same user_id, and instead use a counter column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include `count(*)` in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as totaltimes from table_name 
         GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

If you want only the first one:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as totaltimes from table_name 
         GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I appreciate the response! I have a question though. Can "totaltimes" be anything here? Also, why did you use "Order by 2" rather than count(*) ?

Comment: @Evan:  Yes - totaltimes is just an alias for the output and could be anything (it would need to be escaped with back ticks if it had special characters in it).  The ORDER BY 2 in this case just references the second column in the SELECT list.  For clarity, the COUNT(*) is probably better.  I was being lazy in my typing and will change it.

Comment: Alright, I will give this a try and come back to select it once I get it working.